# SVG progress bar

Tags: css, svg, css-shapes, svg-animate

I have a requirement where I need to load js files dynamically and show the progress of loading files through a SVG icon. The SVG icon will act as progress bar where it fills with a color from bottom to top, linearly.

Here is the [codepen](http://codepen.io/Mr_Green/pen/OXQbpp?editors=1100)

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="79.36px" height="93.844px" viewBox="0 0 79.36 93.844">

  <path fill="transparent" stroke="black" d="M50,2C30-4,8,7,2,28c-6,20,5,42,26,48h0l-4,15l33-18c0-0,0-0,1-0l0-0l-0-0c8-4,15-12,17-22C83,30,71,8,50,2z" />
</svg>
```

I am planning to make this icon independent such that I will only pass the percentage value dynamically.

I somehow able to get the animation done but unable to keep the border or outline of the svg. Here is the [code](http://codepen.io/Mr_Green/pen/wWygmN?editors=1010).

```css
#progressMove {
  transition: .3s y;
}
#progressMove:hover {
  y: 60%;
}
```

```html
<svg id="kenseoProgress" width="79.36px" height="93.844px" viewBox="0 0 79.36 93.844">
  <defs>
    <mask id="bubbleKenseo">
      <path fill="red" stroke="black" d="M50,2C30-4,8,7,2,28c-6,20,5,42,26,48h0l-4,15l33-18c0-0,0-0,1-0l0-0l-0-0c8-4,15-12,17-22C83,30,71,8,50,2z" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <g x="0" y="0" width="79.36px" height="93.844px" mask="url(#bubbleKenseo)" height="100">
    <rect id="progressMove" x="0" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" fill="blue" stroke="black" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

So, the problems I have are:

- Unable to maintain the border to the SVG
- Whatever the color I add is having some kind of opacity which I am unable to remove.
- **Edit**: Browser compatibility:  IE11+, chrome, safari and firefox

PS: I don't want to use SMIL animations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you want to use [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Clipping_and_masking), or set the `mask` fill to white for 100% opacity: `mask` is used as a greyscale alpha channel and the red fill color causes the opacity change.

As for the stroke, you want to add it as a separate element that is not affected by the clipping. *(You can probably re-use the path with `defs` and `use`, I just copy-pasted it here)*

```css
#progressMove {
  transition: .3s y;
}
#progressMove:hover {
  y: 60%;
}
```

```html
<svg id="kenseoProgress" width="79.36px" height="93.844px" viewBox="0 0 79.36 93.844">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="bubbleKenseo">
      <path d="M50,2C30-4,8,7,2,28c-6,20,5,42,26,48h0l-4,15l33-18c0-0,0-0,1-0l0-0l-0-0c8-4,15-12,17-22C83,30,71,8,50,2z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <path stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="transparent" d="M50,2C30-4,8,7,2,28c-6,20,5,42,26,48h0l-4,15l33-18c0-0,0-0,1-0l0-0l-0-0c8-4,15-12,17-22C83,30,71,8,50,2z" />
  <g x="0" y="0" width="79.36px" height="93.844px" clip-path="url(#bubbleKenseo)" height="100">
    <rect id="progressMove" x="0" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" fill="blue" stroke="black" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: This is working Awesome!! I did minimum changes to my existing code. Thanks. Can you please explain why I was seeing opacity to my applied color as I mentioned in question?

Comment: I don't see how this solution is different from the first in my answer, and this only works in chrome

Comment: @Mr_Green The mask is used as a greyscale alpha channel, where black = 0% opacity and white = 100%. The red color you used is translated to a mid-dark grey so it yields 50-60% opacity.

Answer (score 9):

### CHROME/SAFARI SOLUTION

Using the CSS property `transform` and `counter-increment` you can achieve the fill and number increment.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/qezpock9/)**

### CODE SNIPPET

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".progress-container p").append("<span>");
  }, i * 20);
}
```

```css
pattern #progressMove {
  transform: translateY(100%);
  color: purple;
  animation: progressBar 2s steps(100, end) forwards;
}
@keyframes progressBar {
  to {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
.progress-container {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  counter-reset: progress;
}
.progress-container figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-40%, -50%);
}
.progress-container p {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.progress-container span {
  counter-increment: progress;
}
.progress-container p::after {
  content: counter(progress)"%";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<figure class="progress-container">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="79.36px" height="93.844px" viewBox="0 0 79.36 93.844">
    <pattern id="progress" x="0" y="0" width="79.36" height="93.844" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <rect id="progressMove" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" stroke="none" fill="currentColor" />
    </pattern>
    <path fill="url(#progress)" stroke="#000" d="M50,2C30-4,8,7,2,28c-6,20,5,42,26,48h0l-4,15l33-18c0-0,0-0,1-0l0-0l-0-0c8-4,15-12,17-22C83,30,71,8,50,2z" />
  </svg>
  <figcaption>
    <p>

    </p>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

---

*Note:*

Will update if I can give a better solution to cover browser support.

---

### EDIT:

Based on [**Persijn**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39725434/4305494) answer, you will as well have to change the color of the background to that of its parent.

The whole component would be the `figure` element, sadly the symbol in the spritesheet will only be used to provide the path and background.

> Note: jQuery removed in this version.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/mb6v0zk9/)**

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var progressCounter = document.querySelector(".progress__counter"),
      number = document.createElement("span");
    progressCounter.appendChild(number);
  }, i * 20);
}
```

```css
#spritesheet {
  display: none;
}
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}
.icon-bubble {
  font-size: 7em;
  color: white;
}
.progress-container {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  counter-reset: progress;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
}
.progress__inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.progress__fill {
  background-color: purple;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  animation: progressFill 2s steps(100, end) forwards;
}
@keyframes progressFill {
  to {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
.progress__counter {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-40%, -50%);
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.progress__counter span {
  counter-increment: progress;
}
.progress__counter::after {
  content: counter(progress)"%";
}
```

```html
<figure class="progress-container">
  <svg class="icon icon-bubble">
    <use xlink:href="#icon-bubble"></use>
  </svg>
  <figcaption class="progress__inner">
    <div class="progress__fill"></div>
    <p class="progress__counter"></p>
  </figcaption>
</figure>

<svg id="spritesheet">
  <symbol id="icon-bubble" viewBox="0 0 79.36 93.844">
    <title>Loading Bubble</title>
    <path id="bubble-cover" fill="currentColor" stroke="#000" d="M-10,-10 100,-10 100,100 -10,100 -10,-10  50,2C30-4,8,7,2,28c-6,20,5,42,26,48h0l-4,15l33-18c0-0,0-0,1-0l0-0l-0-0c8-4,15-12,17-22C83,30,71,8,50,2z" />
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

### TESTS:

- Chrome 53
- IE10
- Edge
- FireFox 47
- IOS 10 Safari

---

### PLAYGROUND

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/ktxrqos7/)**

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var progressCounter = document.querySelector(".progress__counter"),
      number = document.createElement("span");
    progressCounter.appendChild(number);
  }, i * 20);
}
```

```css
#spritesheet {
  display: none;
}
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}
.icon-bubble {
  font-size: 7em;
  color: white;
}
.progress-container {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  counter-reset: progress;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
}
.progress__inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.progress__fill {
  background-color: purple;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  animation: progressFill 2s steps(100, end) forwards, progressFillColor 100ms linear 2s forwards;
  position: relative;
}
@keyframes progressFill {
  to {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
@keyframes progressFillColor {
  to {
    background-color: green;
  }
}
.progress__counter {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  transform: translateY(-40%);
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  animation: progressCounter 100ms linear 1s forwards;
}
.progress__counter span {
  counter-increment: progress;
}
.progress__counter::after {
  content: counter(progress)"%";
  animation: progressCounterCompleted 1s linear 2s forwards;
}
@keyframes progressCounter {
  to {
    color: white;
  }
}
/* Chrome Only*/

@keyframes progressCounterCompleted {
  33% {
    content: "File(s)";
  }
  66% {
    content: "Uploaded";
  }
  100% {
    content: "Successfully!";
  }
}
```

```html
<figure class="progress-container">
  <svg class="icon icon-bubble">
    <use xlink:href="#icon-bubble"></use>
  </svg>
  <figcaption class="progress__inner">
    <div class="progress__fill"></div>
    <p class="progress__counter"></p>
  </figcaption>
</figure>

<svg id="spritesheet">
  <symbol id="icon-bubble" viewBox="0 0 79.36 93.844">
    <title>Loading Bubble</title>
    <path id="bubble-cover" fill="currentColor" stroke="#000" d="M-10,-10 100,-10 100,100 -10,100 -10,-10  50,2C30-4,8,7,2,28c-6,20,5,42,26,48h0l-4,15l33-18c0-0,0-0,1-0l0-0l-0-0c8-4,15-12,17-22C83,30,71,8,50,2z" />
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

Comment: Yes I need browser support considering IE11+, chrome, safari and firefox. Will update the same in my post.

Answer (score 7):

SVG with pattern and y transition:

```css
svg:hover pattern #fillshape {
  y: 0%;
}
pattern #fillshape {
  transition: y 1s;
  y: 100%;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="79.36px" height="93.844px" viewBox="0 0 79.36 93.844">
    <pattern id="pattern1"
           x="0" y="0" width="79.36" height="93.844"
           patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >

      <rect id="fillshape" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="200%" stroke="none" fill="purple" />

  </pattern>
  <path fill="url(#pattern1)" stroke="black" d="M50,2C30-4,8,7,2,28c-6,20,5,42,26,48h0l-4,15l33-18c0-0,0-0,1-0l0-0l-0-0c8-4,15-12,17-22C83,30,71,8,50,2z" />
</svg>
```

Now this does not work in **Firefox or Edge**. It does not recognize x and y as CSS properties...

Here is a solution that uses a div behind the svg shape.
The downside of this solution is that the svg shape gets a background eg. if you want the shape only you would have to match the background color of the shape with that of the background of the page.

```css
svg {
  position: relative;
} 
.spesial {
  width: 90px;
  height: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: purple;
  margin-left: -100px;
  transition: height 1s;
}
svg:hover + .spesial {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 75 90">
  <path stroke="black" fill="gray" d="M-10,-10 100,-10 100,100 -10,100 -10,-10  50,2C30-4,8,7,2,28c-6,20,5,42,26,48h0l-4,15l33-18c0-0,0-0,1-0l0-0l-0-0c8-4,15-12,17-22C83,30,71,8,50,2z" />
</svg>
<div class="spesial">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I can go with the below solution as it is cross browser supported. But I was hoping maybe I can just keep the div inside the svg itself. because I am using this svg as spritesheet using `use` tag.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var prObject = document.getElementById("prObject"),
  prDom = document.getElementById("progressMove"),
  prValue = 0;

prObject.onmouseenter = function() {
  prDom.setAttribute('class', 'prHover')
};
prObject.onmouseleave = function() {
  prDom.removeAttribute('class')
};

/*prDom.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', '0');*/

var cTimer = setInterval(function() {
  prValue += 20.6;
  prDom.style.transform = "translateY(" + [100 - Math.min(prValue, 100)] + "%)";

  if (prValue >= 100) {
    clearInterval(cTimer);
  }
}, 450);
```

```css
#progressMove {
  transition: transform 0.20s linear;
}
#progressMove.prHover {
  transform: translateY(40%) !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <svg id="kenseoProgress" width="79.36px" height="93.844px" viewBox="0 0 79.36 93.844">
    <defs>
      <path id="mypath" fill="white" d="M50,2C30-4,8,7,2,28c-6,20,5,42,26,48h0l-4,15l33-18c0-0,0-0,1-0l0-0l-0-0c8-4,15-12,17-22C83,30,71,8,50,2z" />
      <mask id="bubbleKenseo">
        <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#mypath"></use>
      </mask>
    </defs>
    <g x="0" y="0" width="79.36px" height="93.844px" mask="url(#bubbleKenseo)" height="100" stroke-width="0">
      <rect id="progressMove" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="blue" stroke="black" style="transform: translateY(100%);" />
    </g>
    <g id="prObject" x="0" y="0" width="79.36px" height="93.844px" height="100" fill-opacity="0" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5px">
      <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#mypath"></use>
    </g>
  </svg>
</body>

</html>
```